# In C, how to improve iteration through list?

Tags: c

I have my own data structure that simulates a heap block.

```
typedef struct heap_block
{
   struct heap_block* next;
   size_t size;
   bool isfree;
} header;
```

I have a method that iterates through my data structure (it is like a list):

```
void craw(header* crawler, bool isfree, int* counter)
 {
   while(crawler->next != NULL)
   {
     if(crawler->isfree == isfree)
     {
         ++(*counter);
     }

     crawler = crawler->next;
   }

   if(crawler->isfree == isfree)
   {
      ++(*counter);
   }
}
```

I need to use additional check because last element have `crawler->next == NULL`

How to improve this iteration?

Comment: if your code is working fine, you may try your luck at http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: How about checking `crawler != NULL` instead then?

Comment: Using a `for ( ; crawler; crawler = crawler->next) { ... }` loop looks simpler.

Comment: Code reviews are best asked at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I you are looking for performance improvements, then it's hard to say without actually profiling the code in a release build. The optimizer can do stuff that you never dreamed of. That said, one thing you could do is to not dereference the counter at each iteration. There's nothing that says its memory will be paged in with the rest of the derefrenced list data, so dereferencing it at each iteration could potentially do expensive fetches. Instead, assign a local counter before the iteration starts, increase it at each iteration and assign the dereferenced counter parameter before returning.

```
void craw(header* crawler, bool isfree, int* counter)
{
    int local_counter = *counter; // assuming counter != 0

    ... iterate ...
    local_counter++;

    *counter = local_counter;    
}
```

Comment: This is, at most, going to affect a single line in your entire cache.  So the perf hit should be absolutely negligible...

Comment: If what you say is correct (which I'm not saying it isn't :)) then I think what you say is that the counter memory is pulled into one cache line and the crawler memory is pulled into a second cache line and that the first one stays put so that dereferencing the counter pointer doesn't miss the cache, even though the second cache line with crawler memory might change - did I get that correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to change the loop test to `while (crawler != NULL) { ... }`, like so:

```
void craw(header* crawler, bool isfree, int* counter)
 {
   while(crawler != NULL)
   {
     if(crawler->isfree == isfree)
     {
         ++(*counter);
     }

     crawler = crawler->next;
   }
}
```

This change will also prevent your code from crashing when `craw()` is called with a `NULL` crawler.

Answer (score 2):

This will probably be the cleanest way you can iterate through a linked list.

```
void craw(header* crawler, bool isfree, int* counter)
{
    for (; crawler; crawler = crawler->next)
    {
         if (crawler->isFree == isFree)
             ++(*counter); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for a call by reference if the result can be returned by the **return value**. So you can change your function to be a *true* function instead of a void *"procedure"* :

```
unsigned crawl2(header *crawler, bool isfree)
{
unsigned count;

    for (count =0; crawler; crawler=crawler->next)
    {
         if (crawler->isFree != isFree) continue;
         count++; 
    }
return count;
}
```

Note: things can get different if you function is inlined. The reference to *counter could be resolved to a direct one in that case (and it even could be kept in a register during the loop)